# Authenticating ASP.NET Web API with OAuth 2 - Best type of Authorization Grant to use?

Tags: asp.net, oauth, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to build the following:

- Website with local user accounts (using ASP.NET MVC)
- API to expose data to mobile apps (using ASP.NET Web API)
- Mobile app(s) (initially Android, connecting via OAuth)

*Note: I don't need to share my data with other providers, but might want to have both an Android and iOS app connecting to the same web service.*

I've created a project using the latest ASP.NET Web API project template and chosen "individual authorization" so that I have access to the ASP.NET Identity system for logins etc.

Looking at the example [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api), I see that it includes the ability to request an access token using the OAuth 2 "Resource Owner Password Credentials" authorization grant, for example:

```
grant_type=password&username=user&password=password123
```

Is it sufficient to use "Resource Owner Password Credentials" type Authorization Grants and simply send the username and password from some textboxes in my Android app, or should I be looking to use an embedded browser to get an "Authorization Code" and then sending something more like this:

```
client_id=myapp&grant_type=authorization_code&code={code}
```

What are the advantages to each approach and if the latter approach is better, where do I begin implementing the "Authorization Endpoint" pages on the server side?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you plan to package your MVC and Web API services in the same web app and hosted on the same domain name?

Answer (score 0):

"Resource Owner Password Credentials" grant is ok if you own all services and don't plan to provide access to them to third party services.

"Authorization Code" grant is needed when you provide access to third parties. Browser page ensures that 
client app does not access user credentials directly(you dont want some unknown app read your users password:)). Also this grant enables some nice stuff like 2FA depending on your geolocation and etc.

If you want to keep it simple in your case - use Resource Ownership.
But if it possible - try code grant.

Also look at [OpenId Connect](http://openid.net/connect/)